# Remove Entire List from List

Tags: python, list, compare

I have a list of lists as shown below:

```
[['Person1', 'www.google.co.uk', '1'], ['Person2', 'www.amazon.co.uk', '2'],['Person3', 'www.google.co.uk', '2']]
```

In my other list I have:

```
[['Person1', 'www.google.co.uk'], ['Person3', 'www.ebay.co.uk']]
```

My desired output would be:

```
[['Person2', 'www.amazon.co.uk', '2'],['Person3', 'www.google.co.uk', '2']]
```

So if it already exists in the other list then remove that list from the original list. Is something like this possible if I do not store the 3rd value of the lists?

Code Tried:

```
ComparedList = [v for v in NewList if v not in List]
```

Comment: Can you supply some code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: The main change from the linked duplicate is that you will need to check whether item[:2] for each item in list 1 is in the second list.

Comment: Consider also renaming your "List" variable to something different since "list" is a protected word in python and it could spare you some troubleshooting as well as help you having better python-style code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the right value to use to search `List`:

```py
NewList = [['Person1', 'www.google.co.uk', '1'], ['Person2', 'www.amazon.co.uk', '2'],['Person3', 'www.google.co.uk', '2']]

List = [['Person1', 'www.google.co.uk'], ['Person3', 'www.ebay.co.uk']]

ComparedList = [v for v in NewList if v[:2] not in List]
print(ComparedList)
```

Output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i in my_list if i[:2] not in my_other_list]
```

Should do the trick.